# Answers to a deleted question not deleted?

Tags: bug, review, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, auto-delete

I just ran across [this review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/2199336) and immediately thought to myself "yes, that should be deleted." But before I recommended deletion, I took a quick look at the question.

What the hell? A red background? The *question* is deleted? Must be a review audit... But then I still get a popup when I click the Recommend Deletion button... Ok, now I'm confused...

Taking a look at the [actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47898/good-practice-projects-to-improve-programming-skills), none of the answers under it are actually deleted.

Is this something to do with the question having been posted clear back in 2008? I mean, it wasn't deleted until 2011 (but automatically), so I wouldn't suspect that to be the problem. Is something else going on here? Should we clearly be blaming Sam for this?

If this isn't a bug, I'd say that LQP review certainly shouldn't be picking answers from closed *and deleted* questions. It's not like anyone can actually see those (and it should be deleted anyways).

Comment: How come [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/48576/9964930) has been deleted by OP 4 mins ago when he hasn't logged in ?

Comment: @Lucifer: That just got deleted by reviewers, through the review item I linked in my question. It wasn't deleted by its owner.

Comment: Ah..ok, so while deleting answer, it doesnt show's reviewer's name like in question deletion.

Comment: @Lucifer: Only if the user legitimately cast a delete vote. When enough reviewers recommend deletion, the post gets deleted by the system on their behalf (it really should get deleted by Community, but that's another discussion).

Comment: Will somebody please tell me..  WHO IS SAM????? lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of those weird side-effects of [migration rejection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations).

See, this question was [migrated to Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69410/good-practice-projects-to-improve-programming-skills) way back in the dawn of time. The stub left on Stack Overflow was automatically deleted after a month. Then somewhat later, the question on Software Engineering was closed - but migration rejection didn't exist at the time, so nothing happened.

Until a few minutes ago, when a moderator on Software Engineering.se *deleted* the question. This finally triggered the migration to be rejected, undeleting and unlocking all of the answers there.

Of course, since the question was deleted it didn't accomplish much, and within about 24 hours, the answers will be re-deleted automatically. But in the meantime, you get weirdness.

Comment: Ah, I see. Those pesky late rejections. Can I plug this here? [Apply the same “rules of migration” to rejected migrations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167473/apply-the-same-rules-of-migration-to-rejected-migrations)

Comment: TL;DR: When a ProgSE moderator gets involved, you get weirdness.

Comment: Looks like Flexo took care of it and ended the weirdness.