# What determines the priority of feature requests?

Tags: support

Is there a "feature request triage team"? What do they consider?

- Does a more recent feature request get more prominence?
- Do more votes make a feature more likely to be considered?
- Is a feature request ignored if it has an "answer"? (even if it's not "accepted"?)

(before marking this as a dup, check the dates - this is a "now" question so anything before 2017-ish probably isn't relevant)

Comment: Dates on duplicates are irrelevant if there are no clear signs the process has changed. So if you've already found one but just dismissed the answer because it was old, think twice. Better to [edit] your question and include why you think the old answer/process is no longer being applied...

Comment: You've made [21 comments (t)here and answered this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356652/282094), yet now you ask this; if only there were a way to incorporate the ideas, rather than ask a new question that fell into an unfavorable voting outcome.

Comment: sorry @Rob. I'm deleting that question. it was a product of frustration that another user just resolved for me.

Comment: I can delete this if you want. but I can also leave it pointing to the dup question that @Tinkeringbell gave me. what do y'all think?

Comment: @Rob I can't delete that other question because of existing answers. but it's junk. help me out?

Comment: LevenTech, I don't need an apology; it was more of an observation / helpful advice. I believe you are stuck with the outcome. It can be difficult to research and ask questions on this site that are well received.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317422/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/282094 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305560/282094

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Is there a "feature request triage team"?

No, there is a product manager for the public platform Q/A.

- What do they consider?

I suspect several sources, in any order: Vision and Goals as set by upper management, the product roadmap, market research, internal feature list (Is the Trello board still on?), surveys, user research, competition,  suggestions posted on Meta.

- Does a more recent feature request get more prominence?

I don't think so although they might be a better fit as those FRs took current features into account.

- Do more votes make a feature more likely to be considered?

SE is not bound to the votes so they could still implement an unpopular FR. I imagine it re-enforces the decision to put an FR into the build track if Meta has voted favorable for a feature.

- Is a feature request ignored if it has an "answer"? (even if it's not "accepted"?)

No, at least I'm told that this certainly isn't true for bugs so I assume the same goes for feature requests. Only a status tag (not being [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)) puts it out of scope for the internal tooling.