# Why is this question NOT automatically deleted by the RemoveAbandonedClosed script?

Tags: support, closed-questions, community-user, auto-delete

[This question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/8593/3955) on Music Fans SE seems to qualify for auto-deletion by the RemoveAbandonedClosed script since it seems to satisfy all the [mentioned criteria](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) for deletion. However, I have been tracking it for several days and it is not yet deleted, though the check is apparently run every day by the Community user.

I'm not sure whether this is a bug, so I've tagged this question as [support](/questions/tagged/support). Any clarification about why the linked question on Music Fans SE is surviving auto-deletion is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if it should make a difference, but the question has been migrated: https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/posts/8593/timeline

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, that seems to be the only "special" thing about the post. Should I add that detail to the body of the question?

Comment: It has an answer... why would it meet the requirements?

Comment: @Catija it is closed and no answers with a score > 0

Comment: also: the roomba forcaster doesn't lie ;)   https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rtcs.png

Comment: @rene Indeed, I found this discrepancy thanks to the roomba forecaster :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turns out that questions which were migrated to the site are not eligible for any automatic deletions outside the 30-day deletion for being rejected.

The check ignored migrated questions because [prior to June 4, 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302349/dont-mark-migrations-as-rejected-if-they-were-closed-long-after-migration) it was only possible for a migrated question to also be closed if the migration was rejected, which would lock the question, and locked questions are excluded from `RemoveAbandonedClosed`. Since that assumption is no longer true, we may want to reconsider that check, especially given a rejected migration would otherwise be deleted despite the lock.

Comment: Hm, I didn't know that such questions were actually excluded intentionally. I thought it was a side effect of the fact that rejected migrations are locked, and locked questions are excluded. Could you please edit the help center page to indicate this correctly?

Comment: Also, to be clear here, does this apply only to `RemoveAbandonedClosed`, or to all deletion criteria?

Comment: @Sonic Ah right, there's another one. The RemoveAbandonedQuestions check does not exclude migrated questions.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Will the check be reconsidered internally, or should a separate Meta question be opened for discussion?

Comment: I have posted a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347703) requesting that the check be reconsidered.